# Use PnP.Framework in Azure GCC High environment within a .net Provider hosted app

Tags: asp.net, gcc

Does anyone know if the PnP.Framework can be used in a GCC High environment within asp.net 4.8 code that needs to authenticate with a SPO. The Azure Web app is a SPO provider hosted add in using

```cs
ctx = new PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(ContractsSiteURL, AppID , AppPwd, AzureEnvironment.USGovernment);
```

Tried this in an Azure GCC High web app and expected the SPO data to comeback the same as when I run it via Visual Studio locally